# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 - Custom Data Format for numeric values

Tags: oracle, format, customization, business-intelligence, obiee

I am facing problems with the custom data format in the latest OBI release.

The following format is used and I have problems in dealing with null values - in this case significant digits, which I still want to be displayed:

```
+$#0,#.0,,M;-$#0,#.0,,M
```

Resulting in (picture 1):

[image: see picture 1]

Removing the first '0' results in (picture 2):

[image: see picture 2]

Is there another -global- option (without adding an extra calculation in criteria tab) for this display? Ideas and suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, the format string should look like

```
+$#,#0.0,,M;-$#,#0.0,,M
```

to get the result you want.

---

**Explanation**

The dot will be replaced with the separator from your locale. So if you are using e.g. the german locale, a number like

```
123,00
```

with a formatting like this

```
#0.0
```

would be written like

```
123,0
```

The comma in the string is the thousands separator. This will also be replaced by the separator of your locale. Again, with the german example the comma would be replaced.

Comment: Hi Tobi, thanks for your reply + explanation. Works great!